GitLab CI curl command failure
Im having problems running an API call towards GitLab to update a group variable in our GitLab instance.
Running the command below works fine when running locally, but Im having issue running the same command with GitLab pipelines.
curl --request PUT \
      --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $GITLAB_API_TOKEN" \
      --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
      --data "$token" \
      "https://$GILAB_URL/api/v4/groups/$GITLAB_GROUP/variables/VARIABLE"

Have also tried
curl --request PUT --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $GITLAB_API_TOKEN" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"value": "'$token'"}' "https://$GILAB_URL/api/v4/groups/$GITLAB_GROUP/variables/VARIABLE"

Error message from GitLab pipelines:
{"message":{"value":["is invalid"]}}
It works when I hardcode the token value in the curl command aswell.
Value of $token "similar to this"
eyJ9ZXGiOiIyIiwidHlwIjoiSldUIiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYiLCJraWQiOiJLNlh5ZFJFZlhJTmNuaDM1WVRsTlFZajNUSDBKQk1MN0VLRWJCLWIz0ENZIn0.eyJzdWIiOiJjMy1vaWRjL2NhdGNoLWFsbCIsInNjcCI6ImFwcGxpZWFiTcGVybWlzc2lvbnMvZ3JvdXBzOlwiZDAzCjUyOTctMWQ0ZS00RGFiLTlkNDEtNDgwZDBkMDk3KuWRiXCIsXCI1OTYzNGRjOC04YzMwLTRlMGUtOThkNC05NDFhOGQ5MTgxNWJcIiwiLCJhdWQiOlsiamZydEAqIiwiamChY0AqIiwiamZtY0AqIiwiamZtZEAqIiwiamZldnRAKiIsImpmeGZlckAqIiwiamZsbmtABosYImpmaW50QCoiLCJqZndrc0AqIl0sImlzcyI6ImpmYWNAMDFlcHk2Zm1xcXJtNWQwdjRyNWdhZTE5cmIiLCJleHAiOjE3MzAzNjU0NjUsImlhdCI6MTczMDM2NTE2NSwAPpIjoiMDdjZTlmZDQtOWQwYS00YmEwLTk3OTYtNWRhZGNlYmQxYTc2In0.FyQ2f1QIRkX3ZeXX2hkgtk1ilZxFFCh6CnRPEufyvaXDLeryvMRGjW73phj45aQiO9MWEHPSDbFVQuKTtxgZUSqZDY7V0osz28OMW5if1tMgOlHkrjre06K37Afbi8UkKvNA-fLn8s0eMut8a6sotKagH8Z5BACG4ziLY7TTQfUTIZSOxMNHyWRrbdSvBL-Nh-4FziCaAY6WdojeZNOpoWp9PLJQrYwEpKrBJ08IYT6Ie5JP2IdFga5ZP4lqc6pLPXfnnU1MBn94HdUVlhFfZUYmlJpD_U4mSA8L5aBgrrw7epUgNRKhCHdJoOhONoCgli5WmqR9NvLBEP53Q5yvCB

Any help here would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Hardcoding token value in curl command by replacing it with $token
Works locally on (mac) / gitlab runners use ubuntu.


Why token is in double + single quote? "'$token'"?

Not sure, thats how it worked on my local machine.
Did not work in gitlab ci (with or without), its reading it as a string and not a token.

Try below that will work
curl --request PUT \
     --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $GITLAB_API_TOKEN" \
     --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --data "{\"value\": \"$token\"}" \
     "https://$GITLAB_URL/api/v4/groups/$GITLAB_GROUP/variables/VARIABLE"

You used single quote within single quote without escape character.

Got the same result
{"message":{"value":["is invalid"]}}

it worked now along with the encoding i mentioned below.
Thanks allot!

Got it working now.
The issue was that my token had a special character "=", so I had to encode it before.
encoded_token=$(printf '%s' "$token" | jq -sRr @uri)

